# Emplace a list within another list

Tags: python

I'd like to call a function that returns a list and emplace its return value within an existing list. Is it possible (without using `extend`)?

Example:

```
def foo():
    return [1,2,3]

def bar():
    return [-1, 0, foo()]
```

I'd like `bar` to return `[-1,0,1,2,3]`.

Thanks

Comment: Your example will return `[-1, 0, [1, 2, 3]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    >>> def foo():
    ...     return [1,2,3]

    >>> def bar():
    ...     return [-1,0] + foo()
    >>> bar()
    [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```